# how do I loop through a certain date range using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql query

```
select * from tableA A where (A.Date>='2019-01-01') and (A.Date<'2019-02-01')
select * from tableA A where (A.Date>='2019-02-01') and (A.Date<'2019-03-01')
...
select * from tableA A where (A.Date>='2020-12-01') and (A.Date<'2021-01-01')
```

Each run will return a different set of results. How do I write one line query to append all results together?

I need to have output as

```
return of line 1
return of line 1
return of line 2
return of line 1
return of line 2
return of line 3
..
return of line 1
return of line 2
return of line 3
..
return of line n
```

Comment: Please provide a few rows of the expected result.

Comment: Do you really want to skip the 1st of each month?

Comment: Use a recursive cte to create all these dates.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific query you can use:

```
select t.*
from table
where t.Date >= '2018-01-01' and t.Date < '2018-10-01';
```

Note:  This assumes that you actually do want the dates on the first of the month.  If you don't, then:

```
select t.*
from table
where t.Date >= '2018-01-01' and t.Date < '2018-10-01' and
      extract(day from date) <> 1;
```